# How to vertically center a div in an Ant Design Grid <Col>?

Tags: antd

I'm sure this question has been asked before, however I couldn't find it anywhere.

Doesn't seem that Ant Design explains how to do this in their docs: https://ant.design/components/grid/

This is what I've tried so far, however doesn't seem to work for me!

```
<Col span={4} style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }} >
   <div></div>
</Col>
```

Comment: You can align columns using `align="middle"`. To align content inside a column needs to be done manually depending on the use case or type of content.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Isn't what I have above manually done? How would I go about doing this manually?

Comment: `alignItems: 'center'` should work, could you provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?